# How can I put the onepage checkout on a CMS page?

Tags: checkout, cms, onepage-checkout

Basically I want to create a one page magento checkout site (similar to this site: https://store.whistle.com/orders/new) where the product and checkout are one the same page.

Is that even possible? If you don't recommend it, why?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I put the onepage checkout on a CMS page?

You can't. Well. Maybe you *could*... maybe iFrame it? But I'm not sure that's what you actually want.

What you're probably looking for is one of the many one-step checkouts that are available for Magento. Here are a few:

[Fire Checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fire-checkout-ultimate-one-page-checkout.html)

[One Step Checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magestore/extension/2805/one-step-checkout)

Those are both paid extensions. Here's a free one:

[Express Checkout](http://store.unicodesystems.in/extensions/op-checkout-extension.html)

Comment: Even if it's the default Magento onepagecheckout, that's great. I just want to get it on the same page as the product, so it's literally a one page website (including checkout) and then a success page.